# How to efficiently animate SVG elements without triggering re-layout

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I want to bring simple animation to the SVG shapes. The problem is that my animation can't be done with just composition tricks like opacity and transform. It requires morphing paths.

Considering that SVG's don't suppose to have layout, just shapes, paths, and vertices in space, I thought that animating them should only trigger repaint of the element; Plus composition. But upon animating path, stroke, or other similar properties, every browser triggers relayout, which does significantly impact render times!

Here's the animated SVG:

```css
body {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

.container {
  width: 60%;
  padding-bottom: 60%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: white;
}

.anim {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.anim line {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke-width: 0.1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg class="anim" viewBox="0 0 2 3">
    <line x1="1" y1="1" x2="1" y2="2">
      <animate
          attributeName="y1"
          from="2"
          to="1"
          dur="2s"
          repeatCount="indefinite"
          calcMode="spline"
          keySplines="0.65, 0, 0.35, 1"
          keyTimes="0; 1"
      />
    </line>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Another option is using canvas and imperative JS instructions to paint it. This does actually improve render times, and triggers only the paint sub-system on each frame. But this approach requires a lot of imperative JS code, while keeping it performant, whereas SVG animations are declarative and are easier to write.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Fq65Qqr. This is chrome profiler capture where the purple segment is layout work, which is done every single frame of the animation. Just inspected firefox, it also does schedule layout each frame. Safari does the same.

I'm animating "y1" property of line element in svg, btw.

Comment: They schedule layout but they don't reflow which is the expensive operation of layout.

Comment: Aha, so I shouldn’t worry about it affecting performance on much on larger pages with more complex layout.